# "unknown exception" in using JavaFX and openCV 3

Tags: java, opencv, javafx, data-binding, webcam

I'm reading serial port and plotting its data correctly. I'm using `LineChart<Number, Number>` series to create a certain graph. There is a `changeListener` method which updates this series whenever data comes in.

In a second stage, I'm using webcam to create a real-time video via openCV. I'm also overlaying a line over it.

**The point is**, one end of the line depends on the data which is the last entry of my `LineChart<>` series.   I'm using the following codes to synchronize the update. It works correctly but sometimes both stages freeze and I get this error:

```
Exception duting the image elaboration : java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
```

It is really strange. If it shouldn't work, why doesn't it throw this exception sooner or at least always?
Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

The codes are really long. I just post the relevant ones:
All codes are in a single class:

Relevant instance variables:

```
 private Series<Number, Number> referenceSeries;
 private Button activateCameraButton = new Button("Activate Camera");
    private ImageView currentFrame = new ImageView();
    private ScheduledExecutorService timer;
    private VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
    private boolean cameraActive = false;
    private ObjectProperty<Number> currentRefValNumber;
    private double currentRefVal = 0;
```

in listner set up method:

```
currentRefValNumber = referenceSeries.dataProperty().get().get(
                                referenceSeries.getData().size() - 1).YValueProperty();
```

And finally here is set up webcam view section:

```
private void setUpWebcamView() {

        Stage secondStage = new Stage();
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();
        activateCameraButton.setOnAction(e -> startCamera(e));
        root2.setCenter(currentFrame);
        root2.setTop(activateCameraButton);
        root2.setId("webcamViewID");
        //root2.getStylesheets().add("-fx-background-image: url('myimage.jpg')");
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2, 800, 600);
        scene2.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());
        secondStage .setTitle("webcam view");
        secondStage .setScene(scene2);
        secondStage .show();

    }

    private void startCamera(ActionEvent event) {
        this.currentFrame.setPreserveRatio(true);
        if (!this.cameraActive) {
            this.capture.open(0);

            if (this.capture.isOpened()) {
                this.cameraActive = true;

                Runnable frameGrabber = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Image imageToShow = grabFrame();
                        currentFrame.setImage(imageToShow);
                    }
                };
                this.timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(frameGrabber, 0, 33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                this.activateCameraButton.setText("Stop Camera");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Camera Error");
            }
        } else {
            this.cameraActive = false;
            this.activateCameraButton.setText("Start Camera");
            try {
                this.timer.shutdown();
                this.timer.awaitTermination(33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println(
                        "Exceprion in stopping the frame capture, trying to stop the camera now....");
            }

            this.capture.release();
            this.currentFrame.setImage(null);
        }

    }



    private Image grabFrame() {
        Image imageToShow = null;
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        if (this.capture.isOpened()) {
            try {
                this.capture.read(frame);
                if (!frame.empty()) {
                    imageToShow = mat2Image(frame);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception duting the image elaboration : " + e);

            }
        }
        return imageToShow;
    }

    private Image mat2Image(Mat frame) {
        Core.flip(frame, frame, 1);

        currentRefVal = currentRefValNumber.getValue().doubleValue();
        //System.out.println(currentRefVal);
        Imgproc.line(frame, new Point(frame.size().width / 2, frame.size().height)
                , new Point(frame.size().width / 2 - (frame.size().width / 40)  * (currentRefVal), 0), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5);
        MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, buffer);
        return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
    }
```

I say again, My code actually works but not always. I'm sysouting the currentRefVal in webcam section and it is getting the correct numbers.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the stacktrace during of which the code still works:

```
Exception duting the image elaboration : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myPackage.MainClass.mat2Image(MainClass.java:486)
    at moradi.MainClass.grabFrame(MainClass.java:473)
    at moradi.MainClass.access$0(MainClass.java:466)
    at moradi.MainClass$1.run(MainClass.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the stacktrace that causes my application to freeze and crash

```
java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.nGetB(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.get(Mat.java:1013)
    at org.opencv.core.MatOfByte.toArray(MatOfByte.java:58)
    at myPackage.MainClass.mat2Image(MainClass.java:493)
    at myPackage.MainClass.grabFrame(MainClass.java:473)
    at myPackage.MainClass.access$0(MainClass.java:466)
    at myPackage.MainClass$1.run(MainClass.java:435)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: 1. Print the entire stack trace in the catch block, not just the exception message. That should give you more information about what is going wrong. 2. You are updating the UI from a background thread with `currentFrame.setImage(...)`. Execute that on the UI thread with `Platform.runLater( () -> currentFrame.setImage(...));`

Comment: @James_D Then what should I do with the timing and that Runnable?

Comment: Don't change them. Just wrap the call that updates the UI in `Platform.runLater(...)`. No idea if that fixes your exception unless you post the stack trace, but you need to do it anyway.

Comment: @James_D I've updated me post. Gonna check your suggestion now

Comment: @James_D Thank you. Your idea is working (I guess it produces a little lag?).   I'm not confident about this synchronization and runLater() staff. I mean I'm not sure what task is being done first. How can I learn it?